# Unable to load any page. Rails app with Webpacker to Heroku App crashed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment, production-environment, webpacker

Before adding webpacker to my application my production environment in heroku was working just fine. The moment i added webpacker i started having this problem.

I searched around for this issue and tried removing /public/packs and those solutions didn't work. I'm having problems trying to access my rails app using webpacker to heroku. I managed to deploy the app, the problem happens when i try to load my app home index page(or any other page in my app). All i have is this info in my heroku logs that fails when i try to make a GET request. Am i missing a configuration?

I'm using Rails 5.1, webpacker and Yarn.

URL for my app is http://semanticworkflow-api.herokuapp.com/

Here are my app logs:

```
2018-10-03T00:07:12.951011+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=semanticworkflow-api.herokuapp.com request_id=2623c8c8-0cff-46cc-be81-7c0b28d3fd90 fwd="191.176.29.243" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-10-03T00:07:13.474152+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=semanticworkflow-api.herokuapp.com request_id=1524e5ad-1bfd-4dfa-b596-4e1c60545903 fwd="191.176.29.243" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

This is my gitignore file:

```
# See https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files for more about ignoring files.
#
# If you find yourself ignoring temporary files generated by your text editor
# or operating system, you probably want to add a global ignore instead:
#   git config --global core.excludesfile '~/.gitignore_global'

# Ignore bundler config.
/.bundle

# Ignore the default SQLite database.
/db/*.sqlite3
/db/*.sqlite3-journal

# Ignore all logfiles and tempfiles.
/log/*
/tmp/*
!/log/.keep
!/tmp/.keep

# Ignore Byebug command history file.
.byebug_history

/public/packs-test
/public/uploads
/node_modules
authorized_keys
```

webpacker.yml file(update):

```
# Note: You must restart bin/webpack-dev-server for changes to take effect

default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker

  # Additional paths webpack should lookup modules
  # ['app/assets', 'engine/foo/app/assets']
  resolved_paths: ['app/javascript/src']

  # Reload manifest.json on all requests so we reload latest compiled packs
  cache_manifest: false

  extensions:
    - .coffee
    - .erb
    - .js
    - .jsx
    - .ts
    - .vue
    - .sass
    - .scss
    - .css
    - .png
    - .svg
    - .gif
    - .jpeg
    - .jpg

development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  dev_server:
    host: localhost
    port: 3035
    hmr: false
    https: false

test:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Compile test packs to a separate directory
  public_output_path: packs-test

production:
  <<: *default

  # Production demands on precompilation of packs prior to booting for performance.
  compile: false

  # Cache manifest.json for performance
  cache_manifest: true
```

Comment: What does your `webpacker.yml` output look like?  It would also be great to see a stacktrace to see what specific error is causing the app to crash.

Comment: added webpacker.yml. I also notice a memory error when i try to run heroku run bundle exec rake assets:precompile.

Comment: for the memory problem in process of precompiling assets on heroku I suggest you to try local compiling https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline